How do I apply parameter extensions to %*?
I already know that %* expands to the complete list of parameters passed to a script.
I also know that, for specific parameters (i.e. %1), there are extensions that extract specific portions of these parameters (for example: %~dp1 extracts the drive letter and path of the first parameter, and %~nx1 extracts the file name and extension).
How do I apply these extensions to the list returned by %*?  I expected %~nx* to work, but it does not seem to be valid syntax.

My current workaround is to redirect the list to a file, use Powershell to remove the directories from said file, then read in the modified content (see below). Obviously, this is messy and inefficient, so I'm looking for a simpler solution.
echo %*>files.txt
set p=%~dp0
powershell -c "(Get-Content 'files.txt').replace('%p%','') | Set-Content 'files.txt'"
set /p files=<files.txt


Better workaround (based on comments): use call set to apply string substitution with the path variable:
set p=%~dp0
set files=%*
call set "files=%%files:%p%=%%"


You might find https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html useful.

@JeffZeitlin yes, the CALL SET example helped me fix the issues I had with one of the other approaches I tried before resorting to file redirection. thanks! this still feels more cumbersome than necessary, but it's considerably better than the first workaround I put together

WinBatch is a kludge piled on top of a hack piled on top of a kludge that started life as something that was supposed to look like CP/M's CCP. Nothing that does anything useful is ever going to look good in code; you're probably better off rethinking it into PowerShell.
